# Problema com herança no css

Tags: html5, css3

Galera estou com um problema com meu códico, bom quero alterar meu códico pra que todos os elementos fique igual. Porém fui tentar fazer isso com o seguinte códico HTML:

```
<div class="button_profile">                                   
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/account/upload">                                                  
  <label class="label"><input type="file" name="file">Alterar foto de perfil</label>                                          
  <button type="button">Chat</button>                           
  <a href="mailto:teste@gmail.com?subject=subject">Email</a>                                                   
 </form>                                                      
</div>
```

E o seguinte códico css:

```
.button_profile button,label, a{
 width:100%;
 font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 color:#fff;
 border:2px solid #fff;
 background:#151515;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:2px;
 padding:5px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

O problema é que ele está modificando os elementos que estão fora da div e eu não quero isso, porém quando crio uma classe resolve e não quero criar uma classe desnecessária,  alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando??? Pela lógica o que estou fazendo é modificar todos os `button label` e `a` que são filhos da div `button_profile`.

Comment: Não, da maneira que você escreveu só o button precisa ser descendentes de `.button_profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao adicionar uma vírgula na lista de tags você está elencando quais são os `targets` para aquele estilo, no seu caso: `.button_profile button,label, a` você está definindo um estilo para todos os `button` que são filhos de `.button_profile`, todas as `label` e `a` da página independente de quem são filhos. Você precisa para cada elemento definir quem é o pai:

```
.button_profile button,
.button_profile label,
.button_profile a{
   ...
}
```

Ou você pode usar tecnologias como o [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) para evitar a repetição de código, seria algo como:

```
.button_profile{
   button, label, a{
      ...
   }
}
```

Que será compilado em um CSS como o exemplo feito antes, porém você não precisa se preocupar em escrever a repetição.

Comment: Ok, mas porque meu códico não funciona sendo que coloquei eles pra modificar os elementos que são filhos de button_profile? O problema é que eles tão modificando até os elementos que não são filhos da div, e porque está acontecendo isso com o meu códico lá em cima? Não entendi bem o porquê.

Comment: Porque com o meu códico ele modifica todos os elementos que citei, mas ele não modifica só os buttons label e a da div, ele modifica também os que está fora, ou seja ... Da página toda :(

Comment: Seu códico funcionou, só não entendi o porquê o meu não :( O que queria era modificar os elementos da div `button_profile` e modificou só que os que não é da div `button_profile` também foi modificado :(.

Comment: Como eu expliquei, quando você usa a vírgula, você está separando quais são os elementos a serem modificados, ou seja `.button_profile button` diz ao CSS para modificar o `button` que é filho de `.button_profile`, mas ao adicionar uma vírgula o CSS irá reconhecer o próximo elemento como um novo, ele ignora o precedente, então ao escrever simplesmente `label` pra ele você quer dizer todas as `labels` da página.

Comment: Aaa entendi, pergunta besta mais tenho que tirar a duvida, pq quando retiro a vírgula ele não funciona ? Ele não modifica nada quando retiro a vírgula, e quando uso o `+` também não funciona, tentei assim pra explicar melhor `button_profile button label a` e ai o códico ... Enfim não funcionou desse jeito, aí tentei `button_profile button + label + a` aí restante do códico, e porque dessas maneiras não funcionou? Porque quando tirei a vírgula eu não separei os elementos! E quando usei `+` era pra tentar concatenar, quero entender pra poder entender bem kkk desculpa se for incômodo.

Comment: Aqui um [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) de referimento sobre os seletores em CSS, irá te ajudar a compreender melhor como funcionam.

Answer (score 0):

Você está alterando diretamente os elementos `label, a` sem declarar seus parentes, tente:

```
.button_profile button, .button_profile label, .button_profile a{
  width:100%;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  background:#151515;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```